# Janus Xml save appointments abstract method fails VB.NET 2010

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, janus

I am using Janus Schedule dll (and other Janus references like janus.common, janus.calendar.dll) to save appointments in a xml file (I am using Janus Winforsv

control suite v 3.0).

I have succesfully run the app in my pc, but when running the program in other pc, the program fails when calling the `SaveAppointments` method, the error comes at **Schedule1.SaveAppointments(stream)**...

The method is:

```
Private Sub SaveAppointments()
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream
        If (fileName Is Nothing) Then
            If (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
                fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName
                stream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            Else
                Return
            End If
        Else
            stream = New System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
            stream.Position = 0

             Schedule1.SaveAppointments(stream)  ''*******HERE IS THE ERROR      

           stream.Close()

            stream = Nothing

            appointmentsChanged = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

The error I get is:

```
 System.TypeLoadException: Abstract Method with non-zero RVA    
at  Janus.Windows.Common.Layouts.PropertyValue.a(XmlWriter , IJanusLayout 
at Janus.Windows.Common.Layouts.JanusLayoutWriter.a(XmlWriter ,  IJanusLayout )    
at Janus.Windows.Common.Layouts.JanusLayoutWriter.FillStream(Stream  stream)
at Janus.Windows.Schedule.Schedule.SaveAppointments(Stream  stream)   
at FOEA.MainForm.SaveAppointments()
at C:\FOE\UI\MainForm.vb:línea 78    
at FOEA.MainForm.MainMenu_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
at C:\FOEA\UI\MainForm.vb:line 143    
at  System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)    
at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.MenuItemData.Execute()    
at System.Windows.Forms.Command.Invoke()    
at System.Windows.Forms.Command.DispatchID(Int32 id)    
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)    
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    
at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m) 
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Fisrt I was suspecting that the target PC needs to have .NET 3.5 for the `Xml.linq.dll`, 
but I referenced the dlls and then I assigned **Copy local** to true, and added all necesary dlls, still throws that error...

Other guess is the name of the `System.Xml.dll`  is not the same as the dll in my bin directory (`System.XML.dll`) maybe the upper case is making vb.net not to recognize the xml dll?, but I don ot thing this has to do with the erro.

I have installed:

- Microsoft .NET 4 Framework Client Profile
- Microsoft .NET 4 Framework Extended
- MSXML 4.0 SP2 Parser and SDK
- MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser

on target pc but that didn't work... When getting that error the contents of xml file are deleted, The file schedule.xml is still there and empty.

I do not know what to do because the program runs in my pc and other I have, but is not running in the target PC... Do you think I should install Janus winforms on target PC? maybe that woulc work

Comment: I just easily doubled your potential audience size with a simple tag change. Judging from your rep count, you've been around here long enough you should've know to do it that way yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Janus sometime ago. 
The method to save appointments that I used is:

```
 Private Sub SaveAppointments()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim appointmentsDir As String = "yourAppsFile.xml"
        Dim appointmentsStream As System.IO.FileStream
        appointmentsStream = New System.IO.FileStream(appointmentsDir, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
        Schedule1.SaveAppointments(appointmentsStream)
        appointmentsStream.Close()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Sub
```

Also verify the xml file to have all roots and elements (well formed XML)

In Janus 3.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Schedule>
    <Fields Collection="true" ElementName="Field" />
    <Owners Collection="true" ElementName="Owner" />
    <Appointments Collection="true" ElementName="Appointment">
        <Appointment0>
            <Description>test </Description>
            <EndTime>10/10/2011 11:00:00</EndTime>
            <Text>test </Text>
            <StartTime>10/10/2011 10:30:00</StartTime>
        </Appointment0>           
    </Appointments>
</Schedule>
```